# Storing jquery selector arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Below you can see that I store the results of the jquery selector in an array. I then use this array to perform other functions. This example here doesn't seem to work, it's behaving as if the var/array is a live selector, not the results when they were instantiated.

```
function flipIt(elementId){
    if (window.jQuery){
        var thisVisibleArray = $('#' + elementId + ' div:visible');

        var thisInvisibleArray = $('#' + elementId + ' > div:visible');

        $(thisInvisibleArray).slideDown("fast");
        $(thisVisibleArray).slideUp("fast");


        /*
        if ($('#flip1').is(":visible")){
            $('#flip1').slideUp("fast", function(){
                $('#flip2').slideDown();
            });
        } else {
            $('#flip2').slideUp("fast", function(){
                $('#flip1').slideDown();
            });
        }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: they are live. the array elements point to the originals. Try cloning the nodes if you just want a copy.

Comment: it's not an array - it is jQuery object

Comment: Please create a demo. A jQuery object is not "live". How do you know that other elements are effected that could not have been selected in the first place?

Comment: i could just loop through each, checking the is(":visible"); along the way... that way i don't end up selecting items I just tried to hide/show...

Comment: I don't understand your question, but note that once you've set the return value of the jQuery factory into a variable, there is no need to pass it to the jQuery factory again when you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select the invisible div elements you have to use not and not ">". And also the 2 variables you defined are already jquery element array so you dont have to use $(). Try this

```
function flipIt(elementId){
if (window.jQuery){


    var thisVisibleArray = $('#' + elementId + ' div:visible');

    var thisInvisibleArray = $('#' + elementId + ' div:not(:visible)');

    thisInvisibleArray.slideDown("fast");
    thisVisibleArray.slideUp("fast");


    /*if ($('#flip1').is(":visible")){
        $('#flip1').slideUp("fast", function(){
            $('#flip2').slideDown();
        });
    } else {
        $('#flip2').slideUp("fast", function(){
            $('#flip1').slideDown();
        });

    }*/
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the selected elements in a variable, and then you are trying to get a jQuery object out of another jQuery object. Just do:

```
thisInvisibleArray.slideDown("fast");
thisVisibleArray.slideUp("fast");
```

Also, they are not arrays, but jQuery objects.